# Calling a model method in a ViewController iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app for iPhone. I have a model class Database, that has all sqlite query methods like login, register and importAllInboxArticles. For login, I have LoginViewController, for register - RegisterViewController. I can successfully define Database* db object in those classes and call login or register method successfully in ViewDidLoad. 
So, this is fine.

However, I am implementing same logic with ArticleViewController : UITableViewController, which supposed to call method `importAllInboxArticles`, form NSMutable array, and then display everything in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {...}
```

So I call importAllInboxArticles in `ViewDidLoad`, but not even NSLog() statement in importAllInboxArticles does not get printed. I also tried to call importAllInboxArticles in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but no result.

Database.m

```
- (NSMutableArray*)importAllInboxArticles:(int)user_id
{

    NSLog(@"Start,Article Importing");

    NSMutableArray *inboxArticles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:20];
    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM Article AS A JOIN UserArticle AS UA ON UA.article_id=A.id WHERE user_id=?"];
    sqlite3_stmt *select;

    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &select, NULL);

    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_bind_int (select, 3, (NSInteger)user_id);

        NSLog(@"Article Importing SQL: %d, SQLITE_ROW: %d", result, SQLITE_ROW);

        while (sqlite3_step(select) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSLog(@"In Article Import While");
            NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:6];

            // add the id:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 0)]];
            // add the title:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 1)]];
            // add the content:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 2)]];
            // add the author:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 3)]];
            // add the date:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 4)]];
            // add the tags:
            [values addObject:
             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 5)]];



            Article* article = [[Article alloc]init];
            article.article_id = [[values objectAtIndex:0]integerValue];
            article.title = [values objectAtIndex:1];
            article.content = [values objectAtIndex:2];
            article.author = [values objectAtIndex:3];
            article.date = [values objectAtIndex:4];
            article.url = [values objectAtIndex:5];
            article.tags = [values objectAtIndex:6];
            [inboxArticles addObject:article];
            NSLog(@"Article added.");

            NSLog(@"Sucsefful loginnnn! %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlite3_column_text(select, 1)] );


        }

    }
    NSLog(@"%d articles were imported form db", inboxArticles.count);
    return inboxArticles;
}
```

ArticleViewController.m

```
   //
//  ArticleViewController.m
//  ReadLater
//
//  Created by Ibragim Gapuraev on 09/06/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Sermilion. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ArticleViewController.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface ArticleViewController ()

@end

@implementation ArticleViewController

@synthesize db,articles;


//- (id)init{
//    self = [super init];
//    if (!self) {
//        self.db = [Database init];
//        self.articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
//    }
//    return self;
//}

- (NSMutableArray* ) articles
{
    if (!articles) {
        articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
    }

    return articles;
}

- (Database* ) db
{
    if (!db) {
        db = [[Database alloc] init];
    }
    return db;
}


//- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
//{
//    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
//    if (self) {
//        
//    }
//    return self;
//}

- (void)setInboxList:(NSMutableArray* )inboxList
{
    self.articles = inboxList;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.articles = [self.db importAllInboxArticles:16];
    NSLog(@"Number of articles in inboxArticles %d", articles.count);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return self.articles.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSLog(@"Number of articles in articles %d", self.articles.count);
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Content";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;

    // Configure the cell...
    Article* article = [self.articles objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *listingKey = article.title;
    //NSString *listingKey = [[[MAIN_CONTROLLER partsCatalog].listing allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *listingValues = article.url;
    cell.textLabel.text = listingKey;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = listingValues ;

    return cell;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}





@end
```

So, why cannot I call methods in ArticleViewController like in other views?
Thank you.

Comment: can you show us where and when `self.db` is defined for the `ÀrticleViewController`? it might be `null`.

Comment: self.db is Database object, which s defined in ÀrticleViewController.h , and I do lazily initialise it in  ÀrticleViewController.m. Thank you.

Comment: Are you getting "Number of articles in inboxArticles %d" in your logs? Is "Number of articles in articles %d" getting called in your logs? 

Because if viewDidLoad is not getting called your ViewController isn't loading properly.

Comment: I guess, I found the problem, Did not initialised db correctly. Now I wrote ...db = [[Database alloc] init];... and database gets initialised. And now, I get all my print lines until if (result == SQLITE_OK) { .. , which I suppose, means that query did not return any result. But when I copy the query and run it in sqlite3 terminal, hit returns result.

Comment: I found the original problem - I did not open and close database. NOW EVERYTHING WORKS. Thank you all for your comments. Sorry for such a stupid mistake) I will answer mmy question after 8 hours, as the system does not allow me to do so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out that you might want to consider to use a regular UIViewController and put the datasource and delegate functions in (a) separate file(s). Your ViewController will become very messy otherwise. Best practice is to avoid UITableViewController in all situations.

If viewDidLoad is not getting called your ViewController is not being loaded correctly. Your problem lies not within your code. If it does, it should also call your database method. How does your UITableView know how many cells to display? Is this the complete listing for your .m-file for the UITableViewController?

If so you are missing the minimum required amount of implemented functions: [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3anumberOfRowsInSection):

Comment: Hi, I have added full ArticleViewController. And, I have provided a comment on some mistakes I have found out, above. Thank you.